# How to set the default background colour of a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am having trouble setting the default colour of a `JButton` to yellow?

Also once the button is clicked it should turn to red and if it is already red it can be clicked to change back to yellow. Any ideas on what I should do?

```
private void goldSeat1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                          

    // TODO add your handling code here:

    goldSeat1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

}                                         

private void goldSeat1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       

    // TODO add your handling code here:

    goldSeat1.setBackground(Color.red);

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the **ActionPerformed** method first (by default) ? and each time check the Color with **button's color getter** before making any change ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need a Mouse Listener here, just use Action Listeners for your JButton.

Comment: For better help sooner please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

To set the back color of the JButton, you can use `setBackground(Color)`.

If you want to toggle the button, you will have to add an `ActionListener` to the button, so that when it is clicked, it changes. You ***don't*** have to use a `MouseListener`.

What I did here is I set a boolean value which flips itself every time the button is clicked. (TRUE becomes FALSE, FALSE becomes TRUE on click). XOR has been used to achieve that.

Since you wanted more properties than the original JButton has, you can customize your own by extending it from `JButton`.

Doing so allows you to enjoy the benefits of the JComponents and at the same time allows you to add your own features.

**Example of my customized button:**

```
class ToggleButton extends JButton{

    private Color onColor;
    private Color offColor;
    private boolean isOff;

    public ToggleButton(String text){
        super(text);
        init();
        updateButtonColor();
    }

    public void toggle(){
        isOff ^= true;
        updateButtonColor();            
    }

    private void init(){
        onColor = Color.YELLOW;
        offColor = Color.RED;
        isOff = true;
        setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));     
    }

    private void updateButtonColor(){
        if(isOff){
            setBackground(offColor);
            setText("OFF");
        }           
        else{
            setBackground(onColor); 
            setText("ON");
        }           
    }   
}
```

**Example of the JPanel to contain the customized button:**

```
class DrawingSpace extends JPanel{

    private ToggleButton btn;

    public DrawingSpace(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        btn = new ToggleButton("Toggle Button");
        setComponents();
    }

    private void setComponents(){
        add(btn);
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){             
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                btn.toggle();  //change button ON/OFF status every time it is clicked
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

**The runner class to drive the code:**

```
class ButtonToggleRunner{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){         
            @Override
            public void run(){      
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Toggle Colors");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.add(new DrawingSpace());
                f.pack();   
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);             
            }
        });             
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this be harder if I created my JButton with GUI Swing?